# Query syntax using cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm having trouble figuring out a fairly simple QUERY statement in Google Spreadsheets. I'm trying to use a cell reference instead of static values and I'm running into trouble. I keep getting `Error: Formula parse error.` with:

```
=QUERY(Responses!B1:I, "Select B where G contains"& $B1 &)
```

I'm sure it is a simple error, but can someone please show me how to write the above so the QUERY is pulling data from B where G contains the value in cell B1 (cell reference)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try syntax of this kind:

```
=QUERY(Responses!B1:I, "Select B where G contains '"&$B1&"'")
```

Answer (score 1):

For dates you need to use something like this

```
=query(Responses!B1:I,"select B where G = date '"& text(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd") &"' ")
```