# Display selected row for match in any columns from a dropdown list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to create a lookup from a dropdown with all unique sheet data that finds a match within any column and returns the selected row items.

Let's say that each row represents a single device with multiple components described in each column with a unique ID for all. How could I search for any ID and get all column IDs associated with that row selection?

I can do this for a specific single column or row with QUERY, VLOOKUP or INDEX, MATCH but perhaps there is a way to make this work for all without a single parent key.

[image: Sample of Goal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return a row based on a match in any cell from a dropdown value.

A `query` will generate the data that you need. Its design is an extension of:

- WebApps question: [Query syntax using cell reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60228/196152) and
- the design of the `where` clause by  [joining multiple conditions using ... logical operators](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where).

---

`=query(A2:D4,"select A, B, C, D where (A= '"&$F$12&"' or B= '"&$F$12&"' or C= '"&$F$12&"' or D= '"&$F$12&"') ",1)`

---

In this answer:

- Cell F12 contains the dropdown
- `where` clause consists of four logical conditions (one for each column) each equal to the dropdown value in F12
- `or` applies for each condition

---

**Screenshot**
[image]